# AngularJs: Applying scope changes from event firing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive which encapsulates a dialog box, and it's almost completely isolated from the surrounding scopes: the only way to communicate with/from it is by firing events. For instance, dialog box commands such as "Apply", "Save", "Delete" or "Turn the lights off" are issued by clicking buttons and firing corresponding events which other scopes may be waiting for.

As we don't know which scopes are registered to handle any specific events, I've resorted to broadcast the dialog's command events all the way up from `$rootScope`, and of course it works. However, if an event handler changes the model, the view isn't updated, because there's no `$apply` or `$digest` following the event firing.

[image]

**Here lies my dilemma:** where to call `$digest` from? Or am I very misguided about the whole thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [$broadcast is synchronous](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/yyH3FYAy5ZY/GVy0ckj29CIJ), I suggest that the code that is calling $broadcast should call $rootScope.$apply() after calling $broadcast, if that code is running "outside" AngularJS.  (If that code is running "inside" Angular, $apply() should not be needed.)

Comment: Yes, the code runs "outside" AngularJS. Given the circumstances, your suggestion is the best option for me. I'm concerned about the weight of calling $rootScope.$digest(), but I'll know if it affects the performance negatively enough.